# How to apply maps to dataframes based on a field value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a script where I loop through a dataframe based on one of its field values.

Something like

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
  "thevalue": [0,0,1,2,2,3,5,5,5],
  "firstname": ["Sally", "Mary", "John","Peter","Julius","Cornelius","Athos","Porthos","Aramis"],
  "age": [50, 40, 30,20,10,20,11,12,23]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
print(max(df['thevalue']))
limi=max(df['thevalue'])
print("=============")

def get_result(df,f):
    n_df=df.query('thevalue==@f')
    print(n_df)
    suma=sum(n_df['age'])
    if n_df.empty:
        return np.nan
    ave=suma/len(n_df['age'])
    return ave
lista=[]
for f in range(limi+1):   #<---replace from here
    print(f)
    #print(df.query('thevalue ==@f'))
    res=get_result(df,f)
    lista.append(res)

print(lista)
```

I want to replace the last for with a map
If I were to apply a map to all rows of the dataframe one by one it would not be a problem but how do I apply it in chunks based on `thevalue`?

EDIT:
The result of the first script (with loops) is

```
   thevalue  firstname  age
0         0      Sally   50
1         0       Mary   40
2         1       John   30
3         2      Peter   20
4         2     Julius   10
5         3  Cornelius   20
6         5      Athos   11
7         5    Porthos   12
8         5     Aramis   23
5
=============
0
   thevalue firstname  age
0         0     Sally   50
1         0      Mary   40
1
   thevalue firstname  age
2         1      John   30
2
   thevalue firstname  age
3         2     Peter   20
4         2    Julius   10
3
   thevalue  firstname  age
5         3  Cornelius   20
4
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [thevalue, firstname, age]
Index: []
5
   thevalue firstname  age
6         5     Athos   11
7         5   Porthos   12
8         5    Aramis   23
[45.0, 30.0, 15.0, 20.0, nan, 15.333333333333334]
```

I would like to have the same output but with maps.
Ergo, the final list `[45.0, 30.0, 15.0, 20.0, nan, 15.333333333333334]` (and if possible the printing like:

```
0
   thevalue firstname  age
0         0     Sally   50
1         0      Mary   40
```

Comment: can you provide desired ouput example?

Comment: yes, hold on a sec, I will edit the post

Answer (score 0):

you can divide dataframe by group with following code:

```
g = df.groupby('thevalue')
[g.get_group(x) for x in g.groups]
```

let's use code above to get desired output :

```
g = df.groupby('thevalue')
range_v = range(df['thevalue'].min(), df['thevalue'].max() + 1)
[(x, g.get_group(x)) if x in g.groups else (x, pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)) for x in range_v]
```

result:

```
[(0,
     thevalue firstname  age
  0         0     Sally   50
  1         0      Mary   40),
 (1,
     thevalue firstname  age
  2         1      John   30),
 (2,
     thevalue firstname  age
  3         2     Peter   20
  4         2    Julius   10),
 (3,
     thevalue  firstname  age
  5         3  Cornelius   20),
 (4,
  Empty DataFrame
  Columns: [thevalue, firstname, age]
  Index: []),
 (5,
     thevalue firstname  age
  6         5     Athos   11
  7         5   Porthos   12
  8         5    Aramis   23)]
```

I made it as tuple, but if you want different type(list or dict), modify it appropriately.

Comment: My problem is that ideally I would like to do it with `map`, because later I would like to do it in parallel.